# How can i delete a self signed certificate in OpenMediaVault?

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, debian, raspberry-pi4, openmediavault

I own a raspberry pi4 with an installation of [OpenMediaVault](https://www.openmediavault.org/).

While checking the available options, i installed an self-signed certificate and force it to always use https.
Now i need to unistall it. How can i do that?

[image]

Unfortunatelly the SSL is marked as referenced and i cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OMV has very poor documentation on installing SSL certificates other than using LetsEncrypt. That seems to be very well documented probably cause it's the easiest to implement. But I wanted a cert that would last me several years and I didn't care about it being trusted by a third-party CA. Anyway to uninstall a cert that is currently referenced with a check mark you will need to at least upload a second pair of certificates (cert & key). Once you have at least a second cert listed you will need to go to the Work Bench menu on the left and then select your new cert on that page to be referenced. Click save and apply. Then go back to the Certificate menu and now you will see the trash can light up on the old cert that was previously referenced. Hope this helps. This took me forever to figure out. I did a bunch of Google searches and no one has this documented anywhere.